# Using begin block while editing in place with Perl one-liner

Tags: perl

I'm trying to get a Perl one-liner working:

```
$ perl -aln -F"\t" -i -e 'BEGIN{print qq(taxid:int:ncbitaxid\tname\tl:label)} print qq($F[0]\t$F[1]\trank,$F[2])' testing
```

The input file for testing looks like this:

```
1    root    no rank
2    Bacteria    superkingdom
6    Azorhizobium    genus
7    Azorhizobium caulinodans    species
9    Buchnera aphidicola    species
10    Cellvibrio    genus
11    [Cellvibrio] gilvus    species
13    Dictyoglomus    genus
14    Dictyoglomus thermophilum    species
16    Methylophilus    genus
```

The desired output looks like this:

```
taxid:int:ncbitaxid    name    l:label
1    root    rank,no rank
2    Bacteria    rank,superkingdom
6    Azorhizobium    rank,genus
7    Azorhizobium caulinodans    rank,species
9    Buchnera aphidicola    rank,species
10    Cellvibrio    rank,genus
11    [Cellvibrio] gilvus    rank,species
13    Dictyoglomus    rank,genus
14    Dictyoglomus thermophilum    rank,species
16    Methylophilus    rank,genus
```

I've been able to recreate this using the following, but I want to edit in place, not print to another file.

```
perl -aln -F"\t" -e 'BEGIN{print qq(taxid:int:ncbitaxid\tname\tl:label)} print qq($F[0]\t$F[1]\trank,$F[2])' testing
```

Comment: what is the error you get?

Comment: Then... what's the problem??

Comment: @qwrrty: the problem is the print in the BEGIN happens before in-place editing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [perlrun, the -i switch for in-place editing](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html).

See [perlvar, $. line number for the last filehandle accessed](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html).

```
perl -aln -i.bak -F"\t" -e 'print qq(taxid:int:ncbitaxid\tname\tl:label) if $.==1; \
                            print qq($F[0]\t$F[1]\trank,$F[2])' testing
```

Comment: Hi codnodder thanks for the suggestion, I was just wondering why was it that a newline char wasnt needed after label in `print qq(taxid:int:ncbitaxid\tname\tl:label) if $.==1;`

Comment: @altimit The `-l` switch provides automatic line-ending processing. See [perlrun, the -l switch](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html).

Comment: **-l switch** 
enables automatic line-ending processing. It has two separate effects. First, it automatically chomps $/ (the input record separator) when used with -n or -p. Second, it assigns $\ (the output record separator) to have the value of octnum so that **any print statements will have that separator added back on**. If octnum is omitted, sets $\ to the current value of $/ .

Comment: @altimit Yes that's it. On a side note, in your case the input line-ending processing is somewhat irrelevant since you are splitting on whitespace with `-a`, so your one-liner would ignore trailing whitespace anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `-i` switch for [in place editing](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#*-i*%5B_extension_%5D):

```
perl -i -aln -F"\t" -e'
  print qq(taxid:int:ncbitaxid\tname\tl:label) if $. ==1;
  print qq($F[0]\t$F[1]\trank,$F[2])
' testing
```

> **-i[extension]**
>   specifies that files processed by the <> construct are to be edited in-place. It does this by renaming the input file, opening the output file by the original name, and selecting that output file as the default for print() statements.

Comment: Agree with your `-i` suggestion, but I think there may be an incorrect interaction between `-i` and the use of a BEGIN block. The default output filehandle is not yet pointing at the file handle being edited in place, so in this case it just prints the header row to STDOUT instead of to the file being edited in place. Please feel free to correct me if I am incorrect. @mpapec